# Hibernate executing different queries in same transaction result in same executed query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying out the combination of spring with hibernate, but I don't seem to be able to execute 2 queries in the same transaction:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Transactional
public void registerUser(String username, String email, String password) {
    System.out.println("Query 1:");
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder1 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UserRecord> query1 = criteriaBuilder1.createQuery(UserRecord.class);
    Root<UserRecord> root1 = query1.from(UserRecord.class);
    query1 = query1.select(root1).where(criteriaBuilder1.and(
            criteriaBuilder1.equal(root1.get("users_name"), "name"),
            criteriaBuilder1.equal(root1.get("users_email"), "email@test.com")));
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query1).uniqueResultOptional();

    System.out.println("Query 2:");
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder2 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UserRecord> query2 = criteriaBuilder2.createQuery(UserRecord.class);
    Root<UserRecord> root2 = query2.from(UserRecord.class);
    query2 = query2.select(root2).where(criteriaBuilder2.equal(root2.get("users_email"), "email@test.com"));
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query2).uniqueResultOptional();
}
```

The result when I call this code is (it is called in a component for the moment):

```
Query 1:
Hibernate: select u1_0.users_pk, u1_0.users_email, u1_0.users_name from users as u1_0 where u1_0.users_name = ? and u1_0.users_email = ?
Query 2:
Hibernate: select u1_0.users_pk, u1_0.users_email, u1_0.users_name from users as u1_0 where u1_0.users_name = ? and u1_0.users_email = ?
```

But I expect query 2 to be:

```
select u1_0.users_pk, u1_0.users_email, u1_0.users_name from users as u1_0 where u1_0.users_email = ?
```

If I switch query 1 and query 2, the result is:

```
Query 1:
Hibernate: select u1_0.users_pk, u1_0.users_email, u1_0.users_name from users as u1_0 where u1_0.users_email = ?
Query 2:
Hibernate: select u1_0.users_pk, u1_0.users_email, u1_0.users_name from users as u1_0 where u1_0.users_email = ?
```

Here is a snippet from my hibernate config:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(DAO_PACKAGE);
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", databaseProperties.getDatabaseType().getDialect());
    return hibernateProperties;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Is the way I configured spring with hibernate not the correct way (or my usage of the query api not correct)?

Info, my dependencies:

- *org.springframework.spring-orm*: 5.2.4.RELEASE
- *org.hibernate.orm.hibernate-core*: 6.0.0.Alpha4
- *org.apache.tomcat.tomcat-dbcp*: 10.0.0-M1
- *org.postgresql.postgresql*: 42.2.10

Comment: You're expecting to only have one query run when you explicitly query twice??

Comment: Also if you're using Hibernate and Springboot, I highly suggest you use JPA and model your database tables as entities

Comment: Then you don't need all this ugly query logic